# foundation css component order

Tags: css, wordpress, sass, zurb-foundation

I am working on a scss compiler for Foundation in Wordpress that uses http://leafo.net/scssphp.

I was curious if the component order of the scss files matter or if Foundation is written in a way that the files can be included in any order.

Currently I have all the components stored in an array and write to a file when the preferences are updated. I don't see any problems with this so far but I am not very familiar with the inner workings of Foundation or SCSS.

Anything I need to look out for here besides the component order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not matter what order they are included.

In the default [foundation.scss](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation.scss) file the components are imported in alphabetical order.